# Etymology of "trastero"

Tags: etimología

("trastero" means storage room)

DRAE, Wiktionary, and [etimologias.dechile.net](http://etimologias.dechile.net) didn't provide any etymologies. I know that there's "tras" (over/beyond), "traste" (cooking utensil), "trasto" (useless thing), and "-ero" (forms places where a general noun resides), but I'm not sure how/whether those words are related to "trastero". Is it that storage rooms are places for useless things?

(En español: DRAE, Wiktionary, y [etimologias.dechile.net](http://etimologias.dechile.net) no proveen etimologías de "trastero". Yo sé que hay "tras", "traste" (utensilio de cocina), "trasto" (cosa inútil), y "-ero" (indica residencia), pero no estoy seguro si/cómo esas palabras están relacionados con "trastero". ¿Es que trasteros son lugares para cosas inútiles?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's pretty clear that it comes from **trasto + -ero**, given that the definition of *trastero* is (DRAE 23<sup>rd</sup> ed., translation mine)

> **1.** *adj.* Said of a piece or of an attic: that its purpose is to store the **trastos** that are not being used.

The suffix *-ero* is used, among other things, to designate a “place where something abounds or is deposited” (DRAE 23<sup>rd</sup> ed., *-ero, ra*, translation mine).  Also be aware that *trastos* doesn't just mean a useless thing.  It can also be used for containers (especially for tools), props or decorations (especially in theater), or furniture.  It's these sense that likely gave birth to *trastero* originally.

The word derived from *tras* is *trasero* and means "behind" (opposite of *delantero*)

---

Creo que es evidente que viene de **trasto + -ero**, ya que la definición de *trastero* es (DRAE 23.ª ed.)

> **1.** *adj.* Dicho de una pieza o de un desván: Que está destinado a guardar los **trastos** que no se usan.

El sufijo *-ero* se usa, entre otras cosas, para significar un «lugar donde abunda o se deposita algo» (DRAE 23.ª ed., *-ero, ra*).  También ten en cuenta que *trasto* no solo significa una cosa inútil.  También puede significar decoraciones (sobre todo teatrales), contenedores (sobre todo de herramientas) o muebles.  Estos significados deben de ser los que originaron *trastero*.

La palabra derivada de *tras* es *trasero* y es el antónimo de *delantero*.